# How does "string".alnum() work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning python on repl.it
The problem is 
Whenever I take a input from user and compare it with .isalnum()
The method always gives the output as True. 
Even if the input is only digits or only numbers

```
    a = input("Enter a value")
    If a.isalpha():
       print "Enter a correct value"
    else:
       print a
```

I have made sure not to include any whitespaces but the output is only to. Enter a correct value

Help appreciated

Comment: isalnum or isalpha. Which one is it? what do you want to do? input an integer?

Comment: Well it returns `True` if all chars are alphanumerical...

Comment: That's what `isalnum()` does, makes sure the string is alpha-numeric chars

Comment: I want the user to only input a integer and not a alphanumeric value

Comment: @user8095199: then you should use `isnumeric`

Comment: But why isn't alnum() working am I making any mistakes?